# Тюнинг Apache по производительности

Tags: apache2, настройки

Встала задача настроить Апач для более лучшей производительности. На данный момент есть проблемы с переполнением памяти и падением сервера.

На сервере только связа Апач (2.2) и PHP 5.5

Общий объем RAM 4 Гб.

Стоит модуль mpm_prefork со следующими настройками:

```
<IfModule mpm_prefork_module>
 ServerLimit 1000
 StartServers 10
 MinSpareServers 10
 MaxSpareServers 50
 MaxClients 1000
 KeepAlive Off
 MaxRequestsPerChild 5000
 ListenBacklog 100
</IfModule>
```

Собственно эти настройки и вызывают большую часть вопросов. Что можно поменять к лучшему?

Comment: А сколько в php `memory_limit`?

Comment: И вопрос, что значит `к лучшему`? Чтобы давать отлуп лишним пользователям? Если есть перманентный переизбыток трафика - пора расти горизонтально.

Comment: @vp_arth лимит стоит в 512 Мб. Но в среднем редко когда доходит объем используемой памяти до 50 Мб на скрипт. А к лучшему - это для начала перестать падать по нехватке памяти.